# Executing junit on remote server in jenkins

Tags: junit, jenkins, remote-server

can anyone help with this.

I am using Jenkins to deploy a build to a remote server, so far so good. However, I want to run JUnit tests on that remote server, but I cannot find how to do this within Jenkins. I have tried it within the ANT but it gives me an error regarding the junit.jar.

I believe that the tests are executing locally rather than remotely.

Any help would be appreciated; Jenkins is a very new experience to me.

Comment: Why cant you make the remote server a slave in the Jenkins setup? Are there any restrictions?

Comment: I don't really understand the point of this.  Why do you need to run the tests on the remote server?  As @ShivaKumar said, if you need tests to run on a particular architecture for some reason, make that machine a Jenkins slave.

Answer (score 0):

Initially you have to be aware of few things. Jenkins is a CI tool which built with plenty of features to make things automated. If you need to run tests on remote server, then follow the sequences to create such a setup :

- Install jenkins on a Machine and properly configure it as CI-Server.
- Deploy your remote server with necessary tools and configure well.
- On Jenkins server, install SSH plugin to run jobs on remote machine via ssh.
- Add the remote server as slave node under **Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes -> Add Node** menu on Jenkins server.
- Configure the node as per your requirement.
- Create a new job which could run the junit tests with pre/post build actions in jenkins.
- Finally schedule the build for slave node and kick it off.

For step by step instructions, refer this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37345305/2383136)