# Run build of Machine A from Machine B using Jenkins

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, testng

I have 2 computers. Com-A, Com-B.

I have build automation functional script using selenium webdriver,Testng and maven on Com-A.

Com-A has installed everything with Jenkins but Com-B has only jenkins , Can I run build which is deployed in Com-A from Com-B? Or I will have to install all necessary software to Com-B also?

Comment: Why don't you check your code in to some repo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your current setup is good enough to kick off the build remotely from Com-B to Com-A.

Please make sure the **jenkins server** deployed on **Com-B** has properly configured as Master and other nodes (ex : Com-A) as slaves.

To ensure the configurations, please follow the steps given below :

- #### *Step 1:*  Go to **Manage Jenkins** page and select **Manage Nodes** link

  [image: Manage Jenkins]
- #### *Step 2:*  On Manage Node page, you can see a list of nodes if already configured. Else there will be only one node named as **Master** by default which represents the host.

[image: Manage Nodes]

- #### *Step 3:*  To add new Node, give a name (ex: selenium-slave1) and select Dump Slave option to add a node as customized slave.

[image: Add New Node]

- #### *Step 4(a):*  After adding the node, configure the node as shown below.

  [image: Configure New Node]
- #### *Step 4(b):*  Make sure while setting the **Launch Method** field, *Launch slave agents on Unix machines via ssh* has been selected (this will communicate via ssh between master and slave nodes).

[image]

- #### *Step 4(c):*  configure advanced fields which are highlighted as per your settings and click save.

[image: Advance Configuration of new Node]

- #### *Step 5:*  Finally a new node has been added as slave and configured successfully.

[image: Node Configuration Successful]

- #### *Step 6(a):*  Now Configure a new Job to schedule it whenever it need to be run.

[image: Add a New Job]

- #### *Step 6(b):*  Add a new maven job since your project has been configured using maven.

[image]

**Note :** Will add the job config soon.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed answer. it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can make Com-A a slave machine in jenkins.  Com-B will become master and mark the build to always run from Com-A node.

Refer https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines

Comment: So for this Do I need to configure Selenium grid?

Comment: Added link - Grid will be required if you want to execute multiple tests parallely - as far as i understand is for you to trigger your tests on another machine

Answer (score 2):

First of all, u don't need to install all thing in COM B.

Connect with COM A with ssh(secure shell) command and than execute ur project using shell or bash script. In jenkins, u will found all build step under Build option.

i use the below command to run my project using shell script:

```
ssh -l user comAIpaddress(ex. 192.192.192.192) sh SciptLocationInComA.shell
```

this command first connect with another machine and than execute the shell script to run the project.

Run a java project using shell or bash script is quite easy..... :)

Comment: Can you provide any tutorial link which help me to complete things using ssh?

Comment: in which os u r doing this test?

Comment: u may try but cygwin sometimes do not work properly, for windows using windows batch command will be best.

Comment: but will batch command allow to run things on another machine without all installation?

Comment: for ssh, u will find a lots of link in url, there is another one option selenium grid....u can also try this to run on several machine ...... :)

Comment: if u can connect to that remote machine, u can also run the batch command there.

Comment: ssh refusing all ports :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111857/discussion-between-noor-and-helping-hands).