# Running Jenkins build from remote

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkins, just finish to configure my first build. My question how can I run Jenkins build from my pc? I mean via command line or some script or java code, I just need to trigger it. Where do I start?

Comment: Do you read `http://<your-jenkins-ip>:8080/api/` ?

Comment: Didn't knew about this, I`ll check it out, thanks!

Comment: Try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37345305/2383136) which will fulfill your need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run build of Machine A from Machine B using Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205447/run-build-of-machine-a-from-machine-b-using-jenkins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try reading the documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) about consuming jenkins API, see the examples using curl CLI tool.

Also here's a [Java API Client example](https://github.com/jenkinsci/java-client-api) for you to inspect.